# Unknown cipher type error on trying execute remote command over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to execute the following command to my remote server:

```
$ ssh user@200.204.45.xx -c "mkdir -p ~/.tmp"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unknown cipher type 'mkdir -p ~/.tmp'
```

What the error above mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to use `-c` to execute command with `ssh`, that option is used to choose a cipher (that's where your message is coming from ...) Just remove it. The `-c command` structure is for local `sh`.

Try:

```
ssh user@200.204.45.xx "mkdir -p ~/.tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier "-c command" used to work, not sure what changed.

Below are some examples you could copy paste and run:

```
# No pem file
ssh ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"

# WINDOWS - CMD
ssh ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"
ssh -i "C:/mycreds/my.pem" ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"

# WINDOWS - GIT BASH
ssh ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"
ssh -i "C:/mycreds/my.pem" ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"
ssh -i "/c/mycreds/my.pem" ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"

# LINUX
ssh ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"
ssh -i "/opt/mycreds/my.pem" ubuntu@11.111.11.11 "echo $HOME"
```